# Use custom URL scheme to send PDF url to iBooks application using as3 and FlashBuilder 4.6?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, pdf, mxml, flash-builder

I'm currently developing an iOS specific app using Adobe FlashBuilder 4.6 and Air 3.4 and all is going well...

My only problem is that the application will be targeting a large collection of PDF files that we have on our website, I want the user to be able to view the PDF files in the native iBooks application. (So that they can email, print etc - StageWebView was an option before I discovered that all action bars are removed in the viewport)

I have tried using this code, the code DOES open iBooks but it does not invoke the load of the PDF file...

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("ibooks://www.website.com/myPdf.pdf"));
```

Is there a way to send the path of the PDF to iBooks using AS3?

Also, is there a way to detect if iBooks is installed before attempting to launch it? 
(Not as much of an issue as I will be prompting users on first launch that they need iBooks but it would be nice to be able to detect if they have it!)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at StageWebView 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248699/open-and-display-a-pdf-file-using-actionscript-for-mobiles-ios

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the itms-books:// and itms-bookss:// schemes?

Also, this looks like a much better solution to me
http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks
but you'll need to implement it through a native extension ...